# Javascript adding multiple products

Tags: javascript

I am stuck trying to figure out the correct syntax for coming up with a number which is the sum of several products. Like this:

```
var sum = (a*b) + (c*d) + (e*f)
```

Please help before i pull out all my hair. There's not much left....

Comment: That is the correct syntax. What is the problem you are facing with it?

Comment: Really!? Im both relieved and annoyed to hear that. Its not working. If I try to put alert(sum); it shows only "NaN"

Comment: How and where are you initializing the other variables?

Comment: The variables are either undefined or strings. If you've received the numbers from input fields they are probably strings, and you should use parseInt(x) on each one.

Comment: Thanks, bvx89! that was it. a few of the variables came from <select><option>, and I didn't realize that they were considered strings.
I got it working now. Thaks a lot for your help. I can finally get som sleep tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved!
Thanks to bvx89  Chandranshu for putting me on the right track:

> The variables are either undefined or strings. If you've received the
>   numbers from input fields they are probably strings, and you should
>   use parseInt(x) on each one. –  bvx89 Nov 19 at 23:21
>
> Thanks, bvx89! that was it. a few of the variables came from
>   , and I didn't realize that they were considered
>   strings. I got it working now. Thaks a lot for your help. I can
>   finally get som sleep tonight. –  Schpenn Nov 19 at 23:28

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can store the products in an array, and then sum all the values of the array.

Something like

```
var products = [];
var total = 0;
products.push(a * b);
products.push(c * d);
products.push(e * f);

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {

    total = total + products[i];
}
alert(total);
```

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question, which is _why_ their code does not work and what to do to fix it.